# Slightly modified version of the same question by the same person

Tags: discussion, questions, asking-questions, duplicate-questions

Is it valid that the same person asks slightly modified versions of the same question?
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8433999/183066), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8431024/183066), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8430243/183066)

Wouldn't be better to edit the original question to get more accurate responses?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct, and you (or others) could compile the content of the questions into a single definitive question, time permitting. But whether you do that or not, find the earliest (or most appropriate / descriptive) and flag the others (as duplicates, so the 'original' is easily traceable) to be closed - a polite message informing the user of their misuse wouldn't go amiss (well, it might to the user, but it's nice to be nice.)

Answer (score 1):

> Is it valid that the same person asks slighly modified versions of the same question?

If the question is just a slightly changed version of an existing question, then it is a duplicate. In the specific case, the questions were the same; what changed is how the questions were phrased.

The OP should probably offer a bounty, if he wants to get an answer that better suits his needs. It still too early to offer a bounty, though, as he asked the first question 6 hours ago (and asked 2 duplicates in 5 hours).