# Response and consequences to a user continually deleting and reposting questions

Tags: discussion, questions, duplicate-questions, post-ban

After reading [Slightly modified version of the same question by the same person](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/115330/slightly-modified-version-of-the-same-question-by-the-same-person) I would like to ask the obvious. What happens if a user continues to post the same questions when he is not getting the answers he wants?

The past few days I have been trying to help on [appengine](/questions/tagged/appengine), and have noticed that a specific user posts and deletes the same questions over time. What can be done in this case? Of course marking them as duplicates is the solution, but for how **much longer** and is that okay? Is there a different approach on this that I am not aware of?

Comment: More often then not, users who do think are not getting answers because of low quality content. So the questions get doenvoted, and eventually the automatic question ban will kick in

Comment: But continue to close as dups and if the user continues, flag for moderator attention, and explain the situation

Comment: @psubsee2003 Thanks, this is clear to me now.

Comment: There's also a daily and monthly question limit -- 6 and 50, respectively -- towards which deleted questions do count. If this is happening over a relatively short period of time, it's likely the user will hit the speed bump.

Comment: @JoshCaswell thanks for the info. Is there somewhere where all these limits/mechanisms are documented?

Comment: There's a lot of info in the various [meta-tag:faq] questions here on Meta, but I'm not sure how you're expecting it to be grouped. [Rate Limit FAQ](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164899), e.g.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that will do as well. I ll try to find my way around with the docs. Have a great day.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Downvoted, deleted and closed questions all count towards the question ban, so this is a situation that will resolve itself (albeit not well for the user).

(Politely) letting the user know that this fate awaits them if they don't improve their behaviour is probably kind though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply it's clear now. I didn't know eg that a question ban existed.

Comment: @JimmyKane its a sad end game for the very worst, so we don't really try to push it in people faces. Anyone contributing normally should never come anywhere near it

Answer (score 3):

Yeah, that's abusive. If you continue to see it, flag it and write in "Other" what you're seeing and a Moderator can investigate.

It's probably a self-correcting problem. If the perpetrator is getting downvotes and deleting the questions he'll eventually run into a post-ban.